# jquery tools display a loader until all flashembed content is loaded completely

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-tools

I tried to use jquerytools for load my swf content by flashembed function.

```
flashembed("flash-background", {
        src: "swf/background.swf", 
        wmode: 'transparent',
        quality: 'high',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        allowfullscreen: 'true',
        scale: 'noborder'
});

flashembed("flash-mp3player", {
        src: "swf/mp3player.swf", 
        wmode: 'transparent',
        quality: 'high',
        width: '100px',
        height: '30px',
        allowfullscreen: 'false'
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- the flash background -->
<div id="flash-background"></div>

<!-- the flash player -->
<div id="flash-mp3player"></div>
```

I'd like to display a loader until all flash content is loaded completely. How could I do? Shall I also use jquery? Thanks

Comment: Can you not add a loader in the same `div` where the flash is going to be? Flashembed will probably override the image as soon as it is done loading.

Comment: the two flashembed swf loading at different times

Comment: Add loader in both `div`s?

Comment: I understand your answer, but I wish they were displayed together once the heaviest has finished loading. Not before the lightest then the heaviest. I was thinking like a flash site that loads all the content before then displays the page

Comment: I don't think that flashembed has a function for that as far as I can tell. You could add a callback function in your SWF's to check they are loaded. If you have both callbacks you can remove the loaders and show the Flash.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find a how-to or how I can do that? Thanks

Comment: You need to implement `ExternalInterface.call()` in your SWF. With this function you can trigger a Javascript function in your page. If you have some knowledge of both Actionscript and Javascript you will get there.

Answer (score 0):

use [$.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) to achieve that

Comment: Can you be more precise about how Paolo can use this function?